# how to add markup to Div dynamically via jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
Markup:
   <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body…</p>
   </div>
```

Why isn't this help?

```
$(".modal-body").val = data_per_folder[current_folder.folder_id].data_per_page[current_page].attachment_extraDetails[attachmentId].attachments_markup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` is a method not a property you use it like this:

```
$(selector).val('new value');
```

Also `.val()` changes the attribute value. A div does not have this HTML attribute.

You want to change the innerHTML. Use `.html()` for that.

```
$(".modal-body").html('new value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .html() instead:

```
$(".modal-body").html(data_per_folder[current_folder.folder_id].data_per_page[current_page].attachment_extraDetails[attachmentId].attachments_markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".modal-body").html ('<your markup code>');`

`.val()` is for html elements not for div/span/p/h/other grouping tags

Answer (score 0):

Try $(".modal-body").val(data_per_folder[current_folder.folder_id].data_per_page[current_page].attachment_extraDetails[attachmentId].attachments_markup);

`val()` is a method for the selected element in jQuery.

Also you can try .text() and .html() methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a `val` property on a jQuery object. This won't do anything.

You may want...

```
$(".modal-body").html(data_per_folder[current_folder.folder_id].data_per_page[current_page].attachment_extraDetails[attachmentId].attachments_markup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML or Append on divs val is for input

so

```
$(".modal-body").html("your stuff");
```

or

```
$(".modal-body").append("your stuff");
```